# how to create msi installer in vs2010 using c#(WCF) that can be installed only on one system

Tags: c#

I want to create msi installer in vs2010 using c#(wcf) so that setup can be installed only on one system(similar to single user antivirus).

for more specific,
hi everyone,

```
            I have a WCF service  (not hosted in IIS) having two functions.
```

1-

String licenceKey=null;

public string getLicenceKey()

```
    {

         //uses AesCryptoServiceProvider to generate licencekey by encrypting machinename

        licenceKey = licence;

        returnlicence;

    }
```

it returns licencekey.

2-

```
           publicboolvalidateLicenceKey(stringlicKey)

    {
```

//uses AesCryptoServiceProvider to decrypt the licencekey

```
        intstatus = String.Compare(decriptKey, machineName);

        if(status == 0)

            returntrue;

        else

            returnfalse;

    }
```

REQUIREMENTS:

1-I want the installer call the getLicenceKey() and show the licencekey to user.

2-It then ask user to enter the licencekey and then call the validateLicenceKey() to validate the licence key.

3-if validation successful then it will be installed else not installet showing message "invalid licencekey".

can any one please help me?

thanx

Comment: what have you tried? where did you stuck? add more details to your question or it will be closed

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I uderstood from your requirement you want to call a webservice as part of your setup. 1. Use WIX http://www.wixtoolset.org/ to create the MSI
2. Use 'CustomAction'  feature of WIX to call the web service via a custom dll say built using c#.